# Why does forking a repo on github only forks the master branch?

Tags: github

When I fork a repo on github, I only see master branch.  The other branches in the repo doesn't get carried over to the new repo.  Why do we call this fork repo when it seems more like forking a branch?

Answer (score 0):

That's not true - I've just checked [my learnGitBranching fork](https://github.com/mgarciaisaia/learnGitBranching), and [it has branches I didn't create](https://github.com/mgarciaisaia/learnGitBranching/branches).

If that's not your case, it could probably be a bug - [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/support) to let them know and help you.

Comment: It's possible the branches were created after the fork.  If that's the case, how do you get them over to the forked repo?

Comment: @Boon, you can always re-fork that project but you would have to deal with Code conflicts.
Or you need to be added as an author of the Repo that way you get instant changes to your forked project.

Comment: @Boon I don't know if you could do that directly on GitHub's interface, but you may clone your fork, add the original repo as an extra remote, and fetch & push those.